# Sharing code in a Xamarin project across .NET Core and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dll, asp.net-core

I've been really struggling to get something that I think should be simple working.

I am trying to create a common class library for referential use across the following project types:

- Xamarin Forms Shared Project
- .NET Core Web API
- .NET Core Console Application

This seemingly simple task has had my stuck all day. I cannot seem to be able to create a simple project with common models that I can reference on all 3 project types simultaneously.

So far I have tried using a PCL, .NET Core Library and .NET Standard Library and none of these have worked.

Comment: "Try making the library netstandard instead."

Comment: Are you using .net standard 2.0 for your common library and .net core 2.0 for the other 2?

Comment: @Hackerman I tried netstandard but it is not referencable by xamarin forms. The shared project suggestion by Alexrgs worked fine with some tweaks.

Comment: @DanielFowler Yes, I have tried using many combinations of different versions and none was compatible with both .NET core and the Xamarin forms shared project simultaneously. The whole process is dreadful, considering the simplicity of simple class sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a **Shared Project**(Yes the old windows classic still alive) where you will move all your common code between the three projects.

Once you reference it, it will compile for each of the projects types you have.

Just be aware if you are using any library you will need to reference it in all other projects.

Comment: Thanks!

I also had to do a little extra work to get files to actually work in the Xamarin projects (everything immediately worked in the .NET Core projects).

I had to open the .projitems file in the shared project folder with a text editor and remove conditionals to the right of each Compile element.